# The performance of AVAssetExportSession(It's too SLOW)

Tags: avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avvideocomposition

recently, I used AVFoundation framework to add water mark to my video, and then export the new video by AVAssetExportSession. The link below show the method and detail.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1

But the speed of export is too slow. it will cost about 20 seconds to export a water marked video which is 1 minute length in iPhone 6sp. Does anyone know how to export quickly?

PS: I try to use preset AVAssetExportPresetPassThrough in AVAssetExportSession. It costs smaller time, but my water mark is gone.

Comment: Encoding 30fps video at 3x realtime speed (~90fps) would have sounded about right for the hardware of 5 years ago, but more recent devices do slow motion recording, which is (I think 240fps), so unless your video is very high framerate, you should be able to get much better performance.

Comment: My video just has 30fps. I guess the main bottleneck of performance is water mark? When I use AVAssetExportPresetPassThrough, I get much better performance, but without water mark.

Comment: How long does non pass through take without the watermark?

Comment: Oh, it costs about 20. It doesn't matter with watermark. And I try to more preset. The cost time will be longer with the high quality preset.

Comment: You should try writing the frames with `AVAssetWriter` to see how long that takes.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Have you found AVAssetWriter to generally be faster than AVAssetExportSession?

Comment: I think AVAssetExportSession uses AVAssetWriter, so I expect the performance of both depends only on whether you transcode (modify frames/framerate) or not (pass through).